# Where can I get a microcontroller board for TI Stellaris?

Tags: arm, kits, development

I'm Looking at using one of the TI ARM chips (see list below) and I'm wondering what I should be looking for to do experiments with, the computer equivalent of breadboarding. I've seen Development boards, Evaluation Kit and a few others. I've also seen price ranges from $50-$5000 (clearly I'm more interested in the $50 end) so I' guessing some of these are WAY more than what I'm looking for. Mostly what I want is a board that wires the chip to power and IO connectors.

The chips I'm look at are TI's Stellaris serise:

```
LM3S{6618, 6753, 6911, 6918, 6938, 6950
     6965, 8730, 8733, 8738, 8930, 8933
     8938, 8962, 8970, 8971, 9781, 9790
     9792, 9997, 9b81, 9b90, 9b92, 9b95}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have one of the Stellaris EKT-LM3S6965 boards. It has an LCD, ethernet and other goodies. All of the pins are broken out to pads.

JTAG is provided by an FTDI chip onboard.

Very easy to work with. See this question for dev tools:
[ARM Cortex-M3 development tools?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/991/arm-cortex-m3-development-tools/3621)

[image]
<sub>(source: [digikey.com](http://media.digikey.com/photos/Luminary%20Micro%20Photos/EKT-LM3S6965.JPG))</sub>

Comment: Do you remember what the price tag was?

Comment: £46.63 http://uk.farnell.com/luminary-micro/ekt-lm3s6965/kit-eval-lm3s6965-enet-code-red/dp/1712253?Ntt=EKT-LM3S6965